# Why doesn't the style in my PaperProps within the MenuProps of my Select apply to the select

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

The white padding in this select won't disappear and I feel like I've tried 30 variations and places to make the css stop showing up. Any advice? This is using MUI 5, and I even tried basing it off of [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/50353676-how-to-change-the-style-of-the-dropdown-element-of-the-material-ui-select-compon-forked-i4468c?file=/demo.tsx) code, where the styling I applied works, so what could be wrong?

Code sandbox with my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-currying-gs9ve3?file=/src/App.tsx)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using a `TextField` with a `select` prop at your base while trying to target the `MenuProps` directly. The TextField API does not have a `MenuProps` but it does have `SelectProps`. Try moving your props into that like so (which worked for me using your sandbox):

```
<StyledTextInput
  select
  defaultValue={"None"}
  displayEmpty
  SelectProps={{
    MenuProps: {
      PaperProps: {
        sx: {
          ".MuiList-root": {
            paddingTop: "0",
            paddingBottom: "0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with`import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';`